# Soundboard app with ringtones

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my soundboard app.  When none of the sounds are played and you try set a ringtone the app stops working. 
I think it has something to do with a variable not being initialized because no sound has been selected.
Any ideas on now I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks for looking. :-)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.sherlocksoundboard.R;


@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class Content extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to back to you
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.Button01, R.id.Button02, R.id.Button03, R.id.Button04, R.id.Button05, R.id.Button06,R.id.button1};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.deargod, R.raw.donttalk, R.raw.lookat, R.raw.stop, R.raw.text,R.raw.john, R.raw.sherlock, };



    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {

                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];

                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();

                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    };





    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }



}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}

@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 

 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }



//Save into Ring tone Folder


public boolean savering(int ressound){
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=50;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    String path="/sdcard/sounds/";
    String filename="Sherlock"+".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "SHRingtone");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Sherlock ");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);



     return true;

}

//Save in Notification Folder

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public boolean savenot(int ressound){
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=50;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    String path="/sdcard/sounds/";
    String filename="Sherlock"+".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "SHNotification");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "sherlock ");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);




    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);



 return true; 



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below "if" statement is kind of "bad programming" but without it the App will crash.
It basically states that if no button is selected then use the first sound in the array.

```
if(soundButton!=null)
{
    selectedSoundId = soundIds[1];
}
```

I put the above "if" statement after this "for" loop

```
   for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
```